# Inserting enum value in a map using spring

Tags: java, spring

I am migrating some of configurations in my project to Spring beans. I am complete stuck at a point where I have to create a map and the value of this map should be the method of an enum.

The java code, which needs to be moved to Spring looks something like

```
map.put(key, Direction.Up.getIntVal())
```

I found a good link [here](http://www.unicon.net/node/601)(http://www.unicon.net/node/601) which allows me to specify a key or val referring to some static field of a class, for instance

```
<util:constant static-field="javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY"/>
```

but could not find any resource which does what I am looking for. Is there a way to achieve what I want to do using Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [FieldRetrievingFactoryBean](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/FieldRetrievingFactoryBean.html)?  You can read up on it [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-constant).  Given that you are trying to code a map, I think the config would look something like:

```
<bean id="enum" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="package.name.Direction"/>
    <property name="targetField" value="Up"/>
</bean>
<bean id="Direction.Up" factory-bean="enum" factory-method="getIntVal"/>

<util:map id="emails">
    <entry key="key" value-ref="Direction.Up"/>
</util:map>
```

I spent some time this morning to validate the configuration and this will work for your needs.  There might be a way to abbreviate the enum bean definition, but I'm not sure.

Comment: do you think this would work when Direction is an Enum and intVal is a private member

Comment: From your initial question, you have a public method getIntVal() on the enum.  By setting the value to `package.name.Direction.Up.intVal`, Spring does a bunch of its magic and actually calls Direction.Up.getIntVal().  That value would then be stored in the bean Direction.Up.  Like I said, I've never actually tried this myself, but am simply going on what I read in the docs.

Comment: @Anish I have updated the configuration above to something that I tested and works this morning.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inject an enum inside a class ,just use the enum value , nt the fully classified name . Since you want the enum's value inside a map ,

```
<bean id="enumBean" 
    class="com.enumClass" factory-method="valueOf">
      <constructor-arg>
          <value>enumVal</value>
      </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<util:map id="enumMap">
    <entry key="key" ref="enumBean.intVal"/>
</util:map>
```

I got a little help from [here](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2007/05/creating-spring-bean-from-java-5-enum.html) . Check if this helps you .

Comment: if I am not mistaken, then here the enum is being defined inside the Spring XML itself. In my case, the enum is in Java and I have to refer to a method of that enum.

Comment: @Ashish , I was thinking that if we need to access an enum's property , we would need to have it as a bean. Have you tried <util:constant static-field="package.name.Direction.Up.intVal"/> 
?

Comment: converting that enum to bean would be my last resort, bcz there are many such enums in my application and I would have to move all of them to bean if I don't get any other workaround. I haven't tried static-field, primarily because that tag is used for public static properties of a class. Here I have a private property of an enum, accessible through a public method only.

Comment: @Anish - Is there a way you can create your own factory class that would provide the appropriate bean/value based on a name?  Might be a workaround that would allow you to get the Enum value as a bean without actually having to define each enum as an independent bean.  Just a thought.